# QField hyperlinks in Android

Tags: qgis, excel, android, hyperlink, qfield

I am using QField for some mobile GIS on Android and would like to have a hyperlink in the attribute table that opens a file stored locally. If not in QField directly then in excel would work. None of the paths I use work; What should paths look like for hyperlinks pointing to files on an Android device? What should they look like if using relative paths?
Is there a way to do it in spreadsheets?

Comment: Very good question !
We have the same wish and we found no solution... Fabrice

Comment: Yeah I cannot figure out how to do it with excel files either. There has got to be some way it I bet it is as simple as a missing set of characters before the file location of the file in android.